# iOS 7 Status Bar Empty Space

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, ios7, uitabbarcontroller

I have an issue where a white space is being created where I think my app thinks it needs a status bar.

I have a `UIViewController`, embedded in that is a UITabBarController. The `UITabBarController` then just displays `UIViewControllers` as normal.

When the app first loads (iPad iOS 7), everything works as expected, only inside that `UITabBarController`, the `UIViewController` (displayed by the `UITabBarController`) is offset downwards by 20 pixels. The space for a `UIStatusBar`.

When I say offset, the `UIViewController` doesn't fall off the bottom of the screen, it just gets shorter to add that 20 pixel space.

This started happening after I enabled the status bar in my `Info.plist` with `View controller-based status bar appearance` = `YES`.

The app only does this when it initially loads. After I change the tab to show a different `UIViewController`, the space disappears.

Any ideas why this is happening and how I can stop this? Thanks.

Comment: its not white space. its white color status bar. you should change the status bar color

Comment: I'm afraid not. My status bar is displayed perfectly well at the top of my view controller. However, inside this I have embedded a UITabBarController, it is this embedded view which is adding the extra space. So it is genuinely just a white space, where it thinks it needs a status bar but isn't one.

Comment: can u plz attach screenshot ?

Comment: Here is a screenshot trying to explain: http://imgur.com/8vtEVdP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't comment yet, but wasn't there a warning, when you tried to place a tabbarController inside of a navigationController? Last time I tried this, XCode threw some warnings regarding the order.

Comment: Nope, no warnings of any kind. I haven't had any issues relating to the tabbarcontroller whatsoever until I just tried adding the status bar. Even now, it might not be the tabbarcontroller, I'm not sure what is causing it.